# Web-based XMPP client (self-hosted and free/libre)

Tags: linux, web-apps, open-source, xmpp

[Next to a server](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/574/60), I also want to host an XMPP client.

#### Client features

It must support the basic features:

- Show my **roster** and the **presence** information of my contacts.
- Allow receiving and sending **text messages**.

And it should support:

- Allow setting my **status** and **client priority**.

#### Administration features

- It should offer some kind of **logging** (failed login attempts, errors, …).
- It should be possible to restrict usage with a **whitelist** per host and JID, e.g.:

  1. allow login from everyone on `@example.com`, and
  2. allow login from `bob@example.net`.

A web interface is not required, I’m fine with configuring it via SSH.

#### Formal requirements

- Must be **FLOSS**.
- Must be a **self-hosted** web app.
- Must run natively on a **GNU/Linux** server.

Comment: Related question for hosted clients: [Web-based XMPP client (for any Jabber ID)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/17197/60)

Comment: [baitisj mentioned **Kaiwa** in his answer to a different question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/25208/60), which, from a first look, might be a suitable solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at [Libervia](https://www.libervia.org/), which is the web interface of [Salut à Toi](http://salut-a-toi.org/).

I think it's pretty much what you are looking for. It's AGPL v3+, very actively developed, and has "social" features like (micro)blogging. I'm working on it, and you can ask us if you need a feature.

There are also [Jappix](https://jappix.org/) and [Movim](https://movim.eu/) which are other XMPP/Web projects.

Comment: Great start, thank you. If you want to improve your answer (→ [edit]), you could point out if and how Libervia matches the desired features (e.g., for the admin: if a whitelist can be used, and if there is a log; and for the client: if it allows users to set the priority; etc.).

Answer (score -1):

[**SparkWeb**](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/sparkweb/):

> SparkWeb is an Open Source, web-based IM client optimized for businesses and organizations. It features built-in support for group chat and strong security. It also offers a great end-user experience with features like group chat room bookmarks, and tabbed conversations.

You can try a [live demo from here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/sparkweb/).