# XMPP or LAN messenger where pasted images are directly shown to recipient

Tags: windows, images, chat

I'm looking for a [XMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) or [LAN messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAN_messenger) where users can paste images from the clipboard and the pasted images are directly shown in the chat window (or a separate window) to the recipient without the need to explicitly download the image or click a link.

Multi-OS support would be a plus but mostly for Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IP Messenger is a LAN based messenger that allows instant sharing of text and images. Check it out at http://ipmsg.org/

Comment: Thanks, great suggestion. The UI is a bit clumsy but the program works very well. I went with this solution, as this does not require a server.

Answer (score 4):

As of (almost) October 2015, it seems that there are several options available to you. For the best experience involving **XMPP**, you will need both **client** and **server** components that support [XEP-0363](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0363.html).

**Server software**:

- [Prosody](https://prosody.im/) with [mod_http_upload](http://modules.prosody.im/mod_http_upload.html) will provide the functionality that you require.

**Client software**:

- [Kaiwa](http://getkaiwa.com/) is a "modern" Web-based XMPP client that supports both
  stream management and HTTP upload for media (including images).
- [Conversations](http://conversations.im/) is an Android application that allows for sharing
  of images.
- [Gajim](http://gajim.org/), paired with the HTTP Upload Plugin, will support sharing
  of images. At this stage, you may have to modify the HTTP upload
  plugin to explicitly allow *copy and pasting* of the image itself;
  however, the client can select an image file to embed in the
  conversation.

Comment: Kaiwa looks like a possible solution for my question [Web-based XMPP client (self-hosted and free/libre)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2383/60). Do you have experience with Kaiwa and would like to come up with an answer? I would appreciate it :)

Comment: @unor, I'm glad that this answer is helpful to you. Unfortunately, I don't have quite enough experience with Kaiwa to answer your question well. I did some research on this subject recently because of my own interest in moving away from Google infrastructure.

Comment: baitisj, thanks for the suggestions. I went with the ipmsg solution in the other answer, as it doesn't need a server, but I keep your suggestions in mind for the future.

Comment: @simon, excellent. I'm glad my answer helped you arrive at the right tool for the job!